# ESP32 Highest Priority Interrupt To Grab Timer Value In Assembly

Tags: assembly, interrupt, esp32, gpio, arduino-esp32

I'm trying to install a GPIO interrupt on ESP32 that records a once per second pulse as precisely as possible. The other running processes (on both processors) delay my normal C based interrupt (ESP_INTR_FLAG_LEVEL3) to make the detection vary by up to half a millisecond.

So my next step is to call an interrupt in assembly which required to use ESP32's higher priority levels. All I need is to grab the hardware timer value and store it in a global variable.

I am not experienced with assembly much less with ESP32 assembly. Here's what I was able to come up with:

```
.global timer0_isr
.global timer0_value

timer0_isr:
    movi a10, 0x3FF5F00C    //Timer 0 Update address into a10
    s32i a0, a10, 0         //A write instruction copies the timer to the timer registers; doesn't matter what is written
    movi a11, timer0_value  //timer0_value address into a11
    movi a12, 0x3FF5F004    //Timer 0 lower 32 bits address into a12
    s32i a12, a11, 0        //Store lower 32 bits to timer0_value
    movi a13, 0x3FF5F008    //Timer 0 upper 32 bits address into a13
    s32i a13, a11, 4        //Store upper 32 bits to timer0_value + 4
```

In C the function and variable are declared:

```
extern "C" {
  extern uint64_t timer0_value = 0;
  void timer0_isr();
}
```

Here is the exception when the function is called:

> Let's get the address: 3FFD1420 <---This is my pulling the variable address in C. It does appear appropriately in A11

> Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (IllegalInstruction). Exception was unhandled.
>
> Memory dump at 0x400d4fc4: eccbd10b 00001bd9 21004136
>
> Core  1 register dump:
>
> PC      : 0x400d4fca  PS      : 0x00060f30  A0      : 0x800d4db2  A1      : 0x3ffb2770
> A2      : 0x3ffd2818  A3      : 0x3ffd1420  A4      : 0x3ffd2c2c  A5      : 0x8814bd16
> A6      : 0x00000000  A7      : 0x00000001  A8      : 0x800d3a99  A9      : 0x00000000
> A10     : 0x3ff5f00c  A11     : 0x3ffd1420  A12     : 0x3ff5f004  A13     : 0x3ff5f008
> A14     : 0x0000000a  A15     : 0x0000033c  SAR     : 0x00000003  EXCCAUSE: 0x00000000
> EXCVADDR: 0x00000000  LBEG    : 0x4008bea9  LEND    : 0x4008beb9  LCOUNT  : 0xfffffffd
> Backtrace:0x400d4fc7:0x3ffb27700x400d4daf:0x3ffb27d0 0x400e44b2:0x3ffb2820

The weirdest part is that I can comment out different sections of the assembly and have it run. I can even have 32 bits copy into timer0_value, though without the update timer instruction, the value doesn't change. The update timer instructions will run if the variable write instructions are commented out

Here's the ESP32 reference: https://www.mouser.com/pdfdocs/ESP32-Tech_Reference.pdf

Here's the Xtensa Instruction reference: https://www.cadence.com/content/dam/cadence-www/global/en_US/documents/tools/ip/tensilica-ip/isa-summary.pdf

Also worth mentioning that I'm using Arduino IDE 2.0

EDIT: The Xtensa documentation has `movi` described "Load register with 12-bit signed constant". Is it possible that the 32-bit addresses are corrupting memory and if so, how do I refer to 32-bit memory addresses for the `s32i` instructions?

Answer (score 1):

So I can't say I have it 100% solved. My best understanding is that high level interrupts are preinstalled with overloadable function names (eg `xt_highint5`) and are allocated to specific numbers in the CPU Interrupt Matrix (page 32: https://www.mouser.com/pdfdocs/ESP32-Tech_Reference.pdf). For Level 5 the interrupt number is 31

Overloading these functions doesn't seem to be possible using the Arduino framework. But on ESP-IDF, I did it using file named `highint5.S` with the following code, much of which was lifted from sample code:

```
#include <xtensa/coreasm.h>
#include <xtensa/corebits.h>
#include <xtensa/config/system.h>
#include "freertos/xtensa_context.h"
#include "esp_private/panic_reason.h"
#include "sdkconfig.h"
#include "soc/soc.h"
#include "soc/gpio_reg.h"
#include "soc/dport_reg.h"

#define TIMR_ADDR_LO 0x6001f004 //(unsigned int*)TIMG_T0LO_REG(0); 
#define TIMR_ADDR_HI 0x6001f008 
#define TIMR_ADDR_UPD 0x6001f00c
#define PIN_PPS 11

#define L5_INTR_STACK_SIZE  12
#define LX_INTR_A15_OFFSET 0
#define LX_INTR_A14_OFFSET 4
#define LX_INTR_A13_OFFSET 8
    .data
_l5_intr_stack:
    .space      L5_INTR_STACK_SIZE

    .section .iram1,"ax"
    .global     xt_highint5
    .type       xt_highint5,@function
    .align      4
xt_highint5:

    movi    a0, _l5_intr_stack // assuming a0 saved restored by EXCSAVE_5 at the end of this
    s32i    a15, a0, LX_INTR_A15_OFFSET
    s32i    a14, a0, LX_INTR_A14_OFFSET
    s32i    a13, a0, LX_INTR_A13_OFFSET

    /* Important: Clear interrupt on GPIO Pin */
    movi    a14, GPIO_STATUS_W1TC_REG
    movi    a15, (1 << PIN_PPS)
    s32i    a15, a14, 0
    memw

    
    movi a14, TIMR_ADDR_UPD    //Timer 0 Update address into a10
    s32i a0, a14, 0         //A write instruction copies the timer to the timer registers
    movi a14, timer0_value  //timer0_value address into a11
    movi a15, TIMR_ADDR_LO    //Timer 0 lower 32 bits address into a15
    l32i a13, a15, 0
    s32i a13, a14, 0        //Store lower 32 bits to timer0_value
    movi a15, TIMR_ADDR_HI    //Timer 0 higher 32 bits address into a15
    l32i a13, a15, 0
    s32i a13, a14, 4        //Store higher 32 bits to timer0_value
    memw




    l32i    a15, a0, LX_INTR_A15_OFFSET
    l32i    a14, a0, LX_INTR_A14_OFFSET
    l32i    a13, a0, LX_INTR_A13_OFFSET

    rsr     a0, EXCSAVE_5 // restore a0
    rfi     5

    .global ld_include_xt_highint5 //Ensures linking
ld_include_xt_highint5:
```

Then the GPIO interrupt source must be attached to interrupt number 31 in C code:

```
#include "driver/timer.h"
#include "soc/timer_group_reg.h"
#include "global.h"
#include "driver/gpio.h"

#include "rom/ets_sys.h"
#include "soc/periph_defs.h"

#define INTR_NUM 31
#define CPU_CORE 1


void timerInit() {
    timer_config_t config = {
        .alarm_en = TIMER_ALARM_DIS,
        .counter_en = TIMER_START,
        .counter_dir = TIMER_COUNT_UP,
        .auto_reload = TIMER_AUTORELOAD_DIS,
        .clk_src = TIMER_SRC_CLK_APB,
        .divider = CPU_SPEED,
    };
    timer_init(TIMER_GROUP_0, TIMER_0, &config);

    gpio_config_t io_conf;
    //interrupt of rising edge
    io_conf.intr_type = GPIO_INTR_POSEDGE;
    //bit mask of the pins, use GPIO4/5 here
    io_conf.pin_bit_mask = 1 << PIN_PPS;
    //set as input mode
    io_conf.mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
    //enable pull-up mode
    io_conf.pull_up_en = 0;
    io_conf.pull_down_en = 0;
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(gpio_config(&io_conf));


    ESP_INTR_DISABLE(INTR_NUM);
    intr_matrix_set(CPU_CORE, ETS_GPIO_INTR_SOURCE, INTR_NUM);
    ESP_INTR_ENABLE(INTR_NUM);
}
```

This much works as expected. However, I'm having trouble adding ordinary low priority GPIO interrupt routines in addition. I'm not 100% sure but I believe there's something important about using `xTaskCreatePinnedToCore` to ensure the interrupts are installed on specific cores. I'll update if I gain any more understanding

Answer (score 0):

The interrupt handler needs to be stored in "IRAM" - "instruction RAM". Otherwise there's no guarantee that the interrupt handler will be resident in executable memory when needed, and the result of calling it will be undefined and unpredictable.

In C and C++ you can do this by using the `IRAM_ATTR` attribute:

```
void IRAM_ATTR void timer0_isr();
```

In assembly you'll need to use `.section` to tell the linker that the code must be stored in IRAM:

```
.section        .iram1,"ax"

.global timer0_isr
.global timer0_value
.align      4

timer0_isr:
    movi a10, 0x3FF5F00C 
    ...
```

Espressif documents the assembly code in [High Level Interrupts](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/hlinterrupts.html). They also include `.align`, which I believe forces the code to be aligned on a 32 bit boundary. I'm not 100% confident this is needed or even that this is what it does.

Comment: Suggestions much appreciated! I will definitely look at that link. I had taken out the iram stuff just to see if I could get it to work outside of the interrupt first. Putting it in causes a reboot but without the register dump. Unfortunately align didn't do the job either. Still so bizarre that certain combinations of movi instructions work, but none of them fail in every combination

Comment: So Xtensa documentation has `movi` described "Load register with 12-bit signed
constant". Is it possible that the 32-bit addresses are corrupting memory and if so, how do I refer to 32-bit memory addresses for the `s32i` instructions?

https://www.cadence.com/content/dam/cadence-www/global/en_US/documents/tools/ip/tensilica-ip/isa-summary.pdf

Comment: It seems I found the issue. A couple of `memw` instructions in between keep the processor from reordering the memory accesses. According to the Xtensa doc: "At least one MEMW should be executed in between every load or store to a
volatile variable". Unfortunately value still doesn't change with the timer, so I might be accessing the wrong memory. Perhaps there's an offset. I'll post the solution when I know for sure that that was the problem

Comment: Cancel that. It seems like it might be a race condition the other core. The `memw` instructions are just changing the timing. 

Not that either. Even when I shift everything over to Core 0 the exception still comes up on Core 1

Comment: This is definitely an esoteric problem :) sorry I don’t have any more suggestions besides IRAM.

Comment: Actually I figured out something else today: `entry` and `retw` instructions rotate the registers and align the stack. I think that that solved the illegal instruction exception (along with the .align 4). I also added the method parameter. Right now, the resulting memory still doesn't change like the timer should and I get "esp_intr_alloc failed" when I try to install it at higher level interrupts. Progress though...